# jQuery Chosen Plugin not styling correctly. Very Small

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-chosen

I've implemented Chosen before, but I'm running into an issue trying to get it to work in MVC 3.  I don't know what is causing this, but the element is rendering as very narrow and I have no idea why.  I've looked all over and I can't figure this out, I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!  Thanks!

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Here is my code:

cshtml:

```
div id="ProducerData" style="display: none;">
                <h2>
                    Winery Information</h2>

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Producer.ProducerID, new SelectList(Model.Producers, "ProducerID", "Name"), "Please select a producer")
                <input type="button" id="btnNewProdcue" value="New Producer?" onclick="NewProducer(); return false;" />
                <table id="ProducerDataTable">
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        SlideWidth = 650;
        SlideSpeed = 500;
        InitTab();


        $("#ProducerDataTable input[type=text]").addClass("DisabledTextInput");
        $("#ProducerDataTable input[type=text]").attr("disabled", true);

        $("#Producer_ProducerID").change(OnProducerChange);
        $("#UserTypes img").click(OnUserTypeClick);
        $("#UserObj_Country").change(OnCountryChange);
        $(".state").change(OnStateChange);
        SetNavigationDisplay();
        $("#UserObj_Phone").live("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which === 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $("#Producer_ProducerID").chosen();
    });
```

Comment: css somewhere else on your site is monkeying with it, use a web dev toolbar like firebug or the chrome debugger that can show all applied styles for an element to track it down.

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing that, but I don't know what it "should" look like.  At least now I know where to focus.

Comment: I've noticed that in line element styling width is set to 0 for some reason.  Does anyone know if it being hidden beforehand might drive this error or something?
EDIT:  This was it - fixed!

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
$("#Producer_ProducerID").chosen();
```

with

```
var opts = {};
if (!$("#Producer_ProducerID").is(':visible')) {
     opts["width"] = 'auto';
}
$("#Producer_ProducerID").chosen(opts);
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me since I wanted to keep the UI hidden until it finished initializing, for a cleaner user experience.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue before.  That `display: none;"` style is the problem.  You should remove it from the div because as the page renders, chosen ignores elements in which are not being displayed.  Therefore it doesn't produce what it should. Try hiding that element after the page has loaded.

Comment: Yep, the hidden element causes Chosen to set an inline style of width:0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed `display: inline-block;` from `.chosen-container` in chosen.css file and solved the issue.